# Why can't i have slashes in my rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I am trying to make an .htaccess file, to create SEO url.

It seems however that I can't have a slash in the mod rewrite, am I doing this wrong?

My code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^folder/folder-name index.php?show=folder&folder_id=7
```

The page is loaded correctly, but the style sheet/images/javascript aren't found!

It's as if, the page thinks that it should look for the style/images/js relative to "folder/folder-name".

If i change the last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^folder-folder-name index.php?show=folder&folder_id=7
```

Then everything is loaded correctly, so i'm pretty sure it's because of the slash.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you're using relative paths in your JS, CSS etc. You have 2 options to fix it:

1. Just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. You can try adding this tag in your page's header:

   ```
   <base href="/" />
   ```

Comment: Great! Thanks, works as a charm :) I will accept as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 2):

One alternative: You can use paths relative to site root.
i.e. change:

```
<img src="images/some.jpg" />
```

by

```
<img src="/images/some.jpg" />
```

Being images folder here: yoursite.com/images