# .htaccess rewriting url for 2 different php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two php mainly - share.php and gen.php

SHARE.PHP
http://example.com/share.php?name=52afcb2793007

while

GEN.PHP
http://example.com/gen.php?name=images/This%20is%20%20%20example.jpg

I am new to writing .htaccess and have been reading on stackoverflow and finding pretty url makers for .htaccess.
So far I can either run share.php or gen.php
My current .htaccess looks like this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^new/?$ new.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^webcam/?$ webcam.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ share.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ share.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ gen.php?name=images/$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ gen.php?name=images/$1
```

It gives a 500 server error when I give a url like http://example.com/someimage.jpg which I guess is because its trying to access share.php and getting the error.

The output I am looking to get is something like this
http://example.com/gen/Image.jpg (where Images will be hyphened instead of %20 - been reading on that as well)
http://example.com/some_id (goes to share.php) - this works which I am guessing is the rule that .htaccess sees first and matches and the id exists so gives the result.

Comment: It's going to share.php because your patterns are exactly the same for both share and gen, so a request `/blah` matches both of them, thus the first rule gets executed first, *always, no matter what*. That shouldn't be causing the 500 server error though unless your php script is returning that.

Comment: So what changes can be done to gen.php so that it differs

Comment: one thing you can do is to preface it with a unique pattern, like `/gen/(something)`, and your URLs will look like what you've linked: `http://example.com/gen/Image.jpg`, then "Image.jpg" gets passed into gen.php as `name=images/Image.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^new/?$ new.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^webcam/?$ webcam.php [L,NC]

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?\.jpe?g)/?$ gen.php?name=images/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ share.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I used the above .htacess and for some reason my css and js files are not being read.

Comment: That's a known issue. See my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20616955/548225

Comment: wow...that worked.... but now the image url which i am getting from $phpvalue = $_GET["name"]; is images/gen/Actual Advice Mallard.jpg ... All my images are under /images, why is this gen being added. I can move the image folder under gen but I still dont get it

Comment: That is because you're using relative path. If you always use absolute path like `/images/Actual Advice Mallard.jpg` then your paths will never get messed up with any pretty URL schemes.

Comment: there is just one addon to this..I will not get a 404 error. Since now any url will be directed to share.php . Is there a specific way to direct only url with jpg ending, or should I check the get method in php and the redirect user to 404

Comment: Yes that can be done  I will edit it as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: I changed `gen.php` rule to restrict it for `.jpg` extension only. However still all the 404 requests will go to `share.php`. If you want only certain requests to be handled by `share.php` then you need to define that requirement like only `/share/something` goes to `/share.php` and rest will generate normal 404 errors.